# Opening and Parsing a QXDM .isf File using Python

Tags: python, python-import, file-format

I'm working on a project where I need to open and parse multiple .isf file formats. Is there a python way to import the data from the .isf file format ? If not is there any other way I could do it ?

The premise of the project is to open multiple .isf files, parse them into one big file, and also analyze the data.

Comment: Are you still struggling with this ? You can use QCAT or QXDM via COM automation, I am happy to formulate an answer if it is still worthwhile to you.

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for QXDM ISF parsing mechanisms, and found only two:

1. for windows with QXDM installed, search manual 80-V5627-1 (ISF Processing Interfaces). "This provides a scripting framework through which any COM-compliant scripting language (VBScript, JScript, PERL, etc.) can access and manipulate files created."
2. if you need to work in Linux or do not have QXDM installed, I found mentioned in Interface Control Documents (ICDS) that those who purchase an ICD are also offered a QXDM Professional ISF Access SDK at no extra charge. This SDK allows you to process proprietary ISF logs directly without conversion to DLF and does not require QXDM Professional to be installed. A copy of the document can be found [here](https://vdocuments.mx/interface-control-documents-icds-qualcomm-control-documents-icds-describe.html).

Since we haven't purchased the SDK and we work in Linux, we convert from ISF to DLF by hand and parse the DLF files in Linux.

Comment: As long as you have access to QXDM and/or QCAT there is a way to use COM automation, either directly against the log file or through QXDM or QCAT COM objects, this can get you quite far in processing log files. The second approach you are describing however is bound to have access to the ICDs which last time I checked is expensive (for an individual that is and even decent sized organizations) and not any easier. I am happy to jump start based on my memory (I do not have access to the code nor the documentation anymore, but I clearly remember how it is done and the examples in perl or JS help.

Comment: as I wrote above, using the reverse engineering of the original converter from QXDM3 - it's easy to write your own converter for ubuntu. the most resource-intensive is the time conversion, it is in different formats. 
Under Win there are no problems with ISF, but a problem in Win. for processing a large number of files, storing, and visualizing them, *nix  is more suitable

Comment: OK cool, if you happen to have access to QCAT, that was released for Linux a few years back and I have used that to parse ISF files as-is on Linux (Cloudera Big Data Cluster that is).  But still you are right that the timestamps for legacy messages are different from the newer ones and some conversion is in order even in the text format. One approach was to use QCAT binary to convert from ISF to Text and then parse the text using Spark in parallel. After a lot of setup and issues it eventually worked quite well, but given the TBs of data the tmp txt files will take a lot of space.